# Переводы стихов

Tags: литература

Как вы думаете, а вообще правомочно ли переводить стихи с другие языки? Ведь от них фактические сохраняется только тема и размер, но той ценности, которую несет оригинал, у них уже не будет. Пусть даже перевод очень хороший сам по себе, но это будет новый стих. Примерно, как басни передавались от Эзопа к Федру, от Федра к Лафантену, а от Лафантена к Крылову и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте сперва разберёмся, что нас может привлекать в том или ином стихотворении.

- Содержание. Интересная история поэмы,  сюжет стихотворения или же философские рассуждения облечённые в стихотворную форму.
- Метафоры и другие лексические выразительные средства.
- Грамматические языковые средства. Под этим я понимаю ритм, размер, звукоряд, подтекст, каламбуры  и другие внесмысловые выразительные средства.

Стихи где главным является содержание при переводе практически ничего не теряют. Басни Крылова ни в чём не уступают, а порой и превосходят лафонтеновские. Стихи Омара Хаяма и пр. Смысла **не** переводить подобные произведения  - никакого.

Переводить стихи, основным мотивом которых являются метафоры и другие семантические тропы сложнее. Не всегда в языке, на который переводят находится адекватное сравнение. Например, почти дословный перевод Лермонтовым стихотворения Гейне "Ein Fichtenbaum steht einsam…" (На севере диком стоит одиноко...) имеет [другой](http://clubs.ya.ru/4611686018427396357/replies.xml?item_no=1091) нежели у автора смысл. Однако, если читателю знакома культура автора оригинала, перевод выходит вполне читабельным. Японские хокку и переводы с английского Маршака пример как раз того как воспринимается перевод подобных произведений.

Стихи ценные своей внесмысловой составляющей, на другие языки практически не переводимы. Пушкинские стихи не воспринимаются иностранцами как раз потому, что сюжет всех его стихов банален, а тропы крайне примитивны, вплоть до полного отсутствия таковых. Привлекает в пушкинских стихах как раз то, что всё это "графоманство" рассказано так обыденно и в тоже время точно, что поэту веришь и сопереживаешь. Передать это на другой язык попросту невозможно.

В целом, большинство стихов вполне переводимо на иностранные языки. Если переводчик хороший, то они начинают даже восприниматься как родные.

Answer (score 1):

Употребив слово "правомочно", Вы имеете в виду юридическую сторону вопроса? Вряд ли подходящее место для выяснения.

Что касается литературной аутентичности, то, безусловно, любой перевод не может быть в полной мере равным оригиналу. Есть ограничения, накладываемые разницей языков, а в стихах - еще и размером и рифмой. Сам по себе перевод есть произведение авторское, и двадцать переводчиков дадут двадцать разных переводов. Поэтому и к нему тоже применимы нормы авторского права.

Comment: +100500
ППКС

Comment: yupaz, не придирайтесь к словам. Вы отлично поняли, что имел в виду автор, так зачем подкусывать? Нравится, да?

Comment: "yupaz, не придирайтесь к словам. Вы отлично поняли, что имел в виду автор"    


@Fuchoin Kazuki, Ваши ли это слова? Не Вы ли приверженец ортодоксальной грамотности? Еще скажите, что слова не имеют значения. В отличие от Вас, я могу понять и простить ошибки в правописании. Но текст, написанный грамотным русским языком, я понимаю именно так, как он написан.

Answer (score 0):

Мне особо-то добавить к [[@yupaz](/users/1370/yupaz)](/users/1370/yupaz) и нечего.
надеюсь, Вы ответите на вопрос насчет "правомочности" - что это значит в Вашем контексте.

Впрочем, есть еще один аопрос.
Ваш ряд Эзоп-Лафонтен-Крылов (Федр сюда, имхо, не ложтся) и т.д. заставляет спросить о том, различаете ли Вы переводы и переложения? 
А переводы... переводы, конечно, нужны.
Шекспира, например, приходится переводить на английский. 
"Слово о Полку..." - на русский.
Басё - на японский... С ним, правда, проще. Можно и не пререводить.